# Numeric data type not storing the values correctly in pypark

Tags: apache-spark, numeric

I am having a problem storing with the decimal data type and not sure if it is a bug or I am doing something wrong

The data in the file is :

> value : "15.957"

When I cast this string in numeric type it become :

> df.my_column.cast("numeric")

> value : 16.0

Why Spark round value when I cast this string to NumericType ?

Comment: If you look into the schema, you'll see it's by default casted to decimal(10,0)

Answer (score 0):

Use FloatType in cast:

from pyspark.sql import types as T

F.col("value").cast(T.FloatType())